# Phaser is not loading the same map created in Tiled software

Tags: javascript, tilemap, phaser, tiled

I have created a sample map using the tiled software. Then tried to load the same on a webpage using phaser.js. But I am not getting the proper result. Is there any mistake in my code or something wrong with the library.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Basic Platformer game</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <script src="js/phaser.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/phaser.js"></script>

   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="phaser-game"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         (function() {

            var game = new Phaser.Game(
            800, 600, Phaser.CANVAS, 'phaser-example', 
            { preload: preload, create: create, update: update, render: render });

            function preload() {
    game.load.tilemap('map', 'background.json', null, Phaser.Tilemap.TILED_JSON);
    game.load.image('tile2', 'floor2.png');
    game.load.image('player','bot2.png');

}

var map;
var layer;
var marker;
var player;
var currentTile;
var cursors;
var curser;


function create() {
    game.stage.backgroundColor = '#787878';    
    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.P2JS);

    map = game.add.tilemap('map');

    map.addTilesetImage('floor2','tile2');
    currentTile = map.getTile(0, 0);
    layer = map.createLayer('Tile Layer 1');


    player = game.add.sprite(20, 20, 'player');
    game.physics.p2.enable(player);
    player.body.fixedRotation = true;

    layer.resizeWorld();

    marker = game.add.graphics();
    marker.lineStyle(2, 0x000000, 1);
    marker.drawRect(0, 0, 20, 20);

    cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();    
    game.camera.follow(player, Phaser.Camera.FOLLOW_LOCKON, 0.1, 0.1);
    game.physics.arcade.enable(player);


      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

And the JSON file is-

```
    { "height":12,
 "layers":[
        {
         "data":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228],
         "height":12,
         "name":"Tile Layer 1",
         "opacity":1,
         "type":"tilelayer",
         "visible":true,
         "width":19,
         "x":0,
         "y":0
        }],
 "nextobjectid":1,
 "orientation":"orthogonal",
 "renderorder":"right-down",
 "tileheight":30,
 "tilesets":[
        {
         "columns":19,
         "firstgid":1,
         "image":"floor2.png",
         "imageheight":385,
         "imagewidth":592,
         "margin":0,
         "name":"floor2",
         "spacing":0,
         "tilecount":228,
         "tileheight":30,
         "tilewidth":30
        }],
 "tilewidth":30,
 "version":1,
 "width":19
}
```

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: See how all the right features seem to be present, but shifted from row to row to make diagonal lines? That's a symptom that your row stride is wrong. If the diagonals travel to the left from one row to the next, your're reading too many tiles from one row, running into the next, so that it starts midway-along when its turn comes, as though it started too early. If the diagonals travel to the right, then you're not reading enough tiles from the row, and some of the leftovers get added to the next row, nudging it over so it starts late. But t's not clear to me where this row size is set/used.

Comment: I have added the files related to the project please do check if there is a mistake I have done in my code or what should I have to add in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code by itself looks alright, but it's hard to tell what the problem is without the source images/tilemap files.

Two possibilities come to mind:

1. You have margin/spacing in between of your tiles in the tileset image.

   - The fifth and sixth parameter of the "addTilesetImage" need to be set to the margin and spacing in between of your tiles (which you probably already configured in Tiled).
2. The tileset image isn't properly exported from Tiled, and not 32x32.

   - Phaser assumes your tiles are 32x32 if you don't pass any dimensions to addTilesetImage and the dimensions are not contained in the json file.

See https://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.Tilemap.html#addTilesetImage for more info.

I would've commented to ask for more info / source files, but lack the rep to do so :).

Comment: There is no margin or spacing in between the tileset image and while creating tilemap I have added tile size of 30X30. But this should not affect the map while loading.I have included all source files, please do check.

Comment: Will do, as soon as I'm home!

Comment: @Ashish Any chance you're modifying tile data in any other part than the create? I've recreated your example based on your create function, and even though you seem to load phaser twice (.min.js and .js) it seems to render properly.

I also turned it into a (slightly altered to load the mapdata inline) fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u7kqrq5f/1/

Comment: You have  loaded the JSON data in a different way, But does it not working by directly loading ? Any idea?

Comment: @Ashish I tested your example locally, using your way to load the json data, and it worked flawlessly. I only changed it in the fiddle as the json data isn't hosted anywhere, so I had to load it inline.

Comment: @Ashish did you manage to fix it? I'm quite curious :)

Comment: the example is working with the json (file)data using inside the project. If I am loading json file in create or preload function then there is no luck. I do not understand this behavior of phaser. Maybe some problem with game.cache.addTilemap() or game.load.tilemap(). I have added code something like this - game.cache.addTilemap('map', null, 'background.json', Phaser.Tilemap.TILED_JSON); Can you try it? Please let me know if any positive result coming?

Comment: @Ashish As I mentioned in my previous comment, I actually did test it with a json file like this: preload: `game.load.tilemap('map', 'map.json', null, Phaser.Tilemap.TILED_JSON);`
Create: `map = game.add.tilemap('map');`
And everything works and renders as intended.

This means the problem is somewhere on your end, possibly in code you didn't list. Perhaps a bug in your phaser version? I can't say, as what you posted just works.

Comment: Ok @vassildador I'll let you after fixing this bug..

Comment: Yep! Its working !!! The problem was version of phaser. I was using phaser 2.0.4 and now I have changed it to 2.6.2. Thanx man.

Comment: @Ashish You're welcome! I'm glad you figured it out. There is also phaser-ce a community-updated version of 2.X which should be compatible with your code. The official version is now Phaser 3, so if you didn't create too much yet I recommend switching to that :)

Comment: Better I should switch to the official version before its too late.

Answer (score 1):

At the very bottom of your json file, I see:

```
"width":19
```

But when I count the tiles across your floorplan, I get 20.

This off-by-one difference can create the kind of row stride error I described in the comment earlier:

> See how all the right features seem to be present, but shifted from row to row to make diagonal lines? That's a symptom that your **row stride is wrong**.
>
> If the diagonals travel to the left from one row to the next, your're reading too many tiles from one row, running into the next, so that it starts midway-along when its turn comes, as though it started too early.
>
> If the diagonals travel to the right, then you're not reading enough tiles from the row, and some of the leftovers get added to the next row, nudging it over so it starts late.